# Access control in content control from main window

Tags: c#, wpf

I had found methods to access main window from usercontrol:

- Window parentWindow = Window.GetWindow(this);
- DependencyObject parentWindow = VisualTreeHelper.GetParent(child);
- Application.Current.MainWindow as parentWindow;

I have some questions:

1. Which of the above methods is the best?
2. How can I access control in usercontrol from Main Window and from usercontrol to usercontrol in the same Main Window?

Thanks,
Skip for my bad English :)

Answer (score 2):

`Current.MainWindow` is ideal in every case because if a `UserControl` is embedded inside another `UserControl`, you can still use `Current.MainWindow` traversing up the tree. All the methods are fine and it all depends on usage and what you're trying to accomplish.

To access a control (lets say **TextBlock**) inside a `UserControl`.

```
TextBlock tb = FindVisualChildren<TextBlock>(usercontrol)

public static IEnumerable<T> FindVisualChildren<T>(DependencyObject depObj) where T : DependencyObject
{
    if (depObj != null)
    {
        for (int i = 0; i < VisualTreeHelper.GetChildrenCount(depObj); i++)
        {
            DependencyObject child = VisualTreeHelper.GetChild(depObj, i);
            if (child != null && child is T)
            {
                yield return (T)child;
            }

            foreach (T childOfChild in FindVisualChildren<T>(child))
            {
                yield return childOfChild;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

None of the suggested is "best":

`Application.Current.MainWindow` or `Window.GetWindow(this)`:
not good since you're breaking with common design patterns and rules (like "principle dependency inversion" or MVVM)

Using `VisualTreeHelper` is sometimes useful when coding XAML Converters (such elements that directly deal with the UI). Not preferrable in code since you're strongly depending on your xaml visual tree.

If you want to communicate between the `MainWindow` and a `UserControl`, keeping a resuable `UserControl` for other assemblies, add one or more [dependency properties](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/140620/WPF-Tutorial-Dependency-Property) to your Usercontrol, and set the binding in Xaml.

If you want quick and easy test apps, sure Application.Current.MainWindow is still a good choice.